# How to prioritize write() over mmap updates (or delay mmap page cache flush)

Tags: linux, memory-management, mmap

I'm running a specialized DB daemon on a debian-64 with 64G of RAM and lots of disk space. It uses an on-disk hashtable (mmaped) and writes the actual data into a file with regular write() calls. When doing really a lot of updates, a big part of the mmap gets dirty and the page cache tries to flush it to disk, producing lots of random writes which in turn slows down the performance of the regular (sequential) writes to the data file.

If it were possible to delay the page cache flush of the mmaped area performance would improve (I assume), since several (or all) changes to the dirty page would be written at once instead of once for every update (worst case, in reality of course it aggregates a lot of changes anyway).

So my question: Is it possible to delay page cache flush for a memory-mapped area? Or is it possible to prioritze the regular write? Or does anyone have any other ideas? madvise and posix_fadvise don't seem to make any difference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could play with the tuneables in `/proc/sys/vm`. For example, increase the value in `dirty_writeback_centisecs` to make pdflush wake up somewhat less often, increase `dirty_expire_centiseconds` so data is allowed to stay dirty for longer until it must be written out, and increase `dirty_background_ratio` to allow more dirty pages to stay in RAM before something must be done.
See [here](http://www.westnet.com/~gsmith/content/linux-pdflush.htm) for a somewhat comprehensive description of what all the values do.

Note that this will affect **every** process on your machine, but seeing how you're running a huge database server, chances are that this is no problem since you don't want anything else to run on the same machine anyway.

Now of course this delays writes, but it still doesn't fully solve the problem of dirty page writebacks competing with `write` (though it will likely collapse a few writes if there are many updates).
**But:** You *can* use the [`sync_file_range`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/arm_sync_file_range.2.html) syscall to force beginning write-out of pages in a given range on your "write" file descriptor (`SYNC_FILE_RANGE_WRITE`). So while the dirty pages will be written back at some unknown time later (and with greater grace periods), you manually kick off writeback on the ones you're interested.
This doesn't give any guarantees, but it *should* just work.

Be sure to absolutely positively read the documentation, better read it twice. `sync_file_range` can very easily corrupt or lose data if you use it wrong. In particular, you must be sure metadata is up-to-date and flushed if you appended to a file, or data that has been "successfully written" will just be "gone" in case of a crash.

Comment: that sounds reasonable (though i think i have to increase dirty_ratio, too), i will give it a try during the next weeks and let you know the results. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try [mlock](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlockall). If you `mlock` the relevant memory range, it may prevent the flush from occurring. You could `munlock` when you're done.

Comment: Though mlock probably will work, it is not by avoiding the flush. It is because the fysical memory will stick to the address-range, so pages can not be stolen *after* they are flushed (and have not been referenced for a very long time) The exact problem of course is that the access to the hashtable will be very sparse and spurious: there is a chance that some page will not be referenced for a very long time (and will be dropped out of core by the LRU). Mlock will probably work (if memory is not too tight)

Comment: the problem isn't that it needs to reload relevant parts of the hash-table from disk (the hash-table isn't all that sparse and big, i tried a scenario where everything fits into ram, including the data), the problem is that the actual write operations of the page flush cause significant disk i/o (because they get dirtied so often) which slows down the writes to the data file (of course this is unavoidable, but the question is whether it could be mitigated)

Comment: The problem is that in (good) hashtables, access patterns are always disperse. Issuing N updates on a hash table that covers N pages, will hit about (2/3) \*N pages. Only approx. N/3 pages will *not* be hit. The only way to avoid this is not using mmap (or a anonymous/private mapping), and invent some other way to apply the updates to the disk file.